Minimizing the functional $\int_0^1 x y(x) y'(x) \mathrm{d}x$
I'm asked to analyze the variational problem corresponding to the functional
$$
J(y) = \int_0^1 x y(x) y'(x) \mathrm{d}x\qquad y(0) = 0, \text{ }  y(1)=1.
$$
So, what I did was to use Euler-Lagrange's equation to find its extremals.
I get the equation $xy'(x) = y(x) + xy'(x)$ which reduces to $y(x) =0$.
This implies that there is only one extremal, namely, the constant function equal to zero.
Since this function does not satisfies $y(1) = 1$, it cannot be a critical  point.
Therefore, $J$ has no minima nor maxima.
Is my analysis correct?

For what it's worth, another proof uses integration by parts:
$$  J[y] ~=~  \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\mathrm{d}x~ x \frac{dy(x)^2}{dx}  
~\stackrel{\rm IBP}{=}~  \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\mathrm{d}x~ y(x)^2. $$

Clearly, there is no minimum as we can choose $|y|$ as large as we want in the bulk (=away from the boundary).

To reach a maximum, we should apparently choose $y(x)=0$, but that doesn't satisfy the boundary conditions, as OP already has observed.



That $J[y]<1/2$ is also supported by the test function $y(x)=x^p$ with $p>0$. Then $J[y]=p/(2p+1)\to 1/2$ as $p\to \infty$. Similarly, the test function $y(x)=x(1+a-ax)$ yields $J[y]=1/3-a/12-a^2/60\to -\infty$ as $a\to \infty$.

Yes - but there is no extrema here.
After applying the euler's equation we get$\hspace{1mm}$ $y(x)=0$. Where one of the Boundary conditions doesn't satisfied.
Hence no extremal for the given probelm. 
So no need to talk about Minima or Maxima.

I think you mean "no extrema"

Yes No extrema. Some books use extrema some use extremal.
